# "Неправильный" размер элементов управления WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Делаю проект WPF в Visual Studio. В визуальном конструкторе всё нормально, в коде всё вроде бы тоже правильно. На всякий случай вот участок код XAML:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Menu Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File" FontSize="15">
                <MenuItem Header="New"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open"></MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Name="ExitButton" Header="Exit" Click="ExitButton_Click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" FontSize="15"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help" FontSize="15"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,22,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Height="412"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Вот как всё выглядит в редакторе]

Но когда я запускаю приложение то ли главное окно "сжимается", то ли элементы управления "увеличиваются". То же самое и со всякими кнопками и т.д. во всех WPF проектах. Из-за этого приходится постоянно делать отступы от краёв окна.
С чем это связано? Как это можно убрать, если вообще можно?
[image: Вот как выглядит в приложении]

Comment: `Width="800" Height="412"` - не делайте так, дайте свободу контролам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда не ориентируйтесь на визуальный редактор как на истину. Отступы в визуальном редакторе не учитывают визуальный стиль окна WPF для данной операционной системы.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Padding="5">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>      
        <MenuItem Header="File">
           <MenuItem Header="New"/>
           <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
           <Separator/>
           <MenuItem Name="ExitButton" Header="Exit" Click="ExitButton_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
    </Menu>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

Задавать размеры контролам в пикселях крайне не рекомендуется, управляйте отступами с помощью марджинов и паддингов. Пишите XAML руками.

К тому же, если не указывать размеры в пикселях, контролы будут автоматически подстраиваться при изменении размеров окна пользователем.

Comment: Спасибо большое.